# Parsing property with multiple possible content

Tags: groovy, jackson

`data` response content is dynamic, if the response is ok, it must be parse to QueryResponse and if the response contains an error ( checking String type value if != 200 ), it must be parse to ErrorData. How can I do this with @JsonProperty/@JsonIgnore?

**Current code:**

class `GenericResponse`

```
int type

ErrorData data
```

class `QueryResponse` extends `GenericResponse`

```
String data
```

Comment: Why not do it in code based on the status and a couple of custom deserialisers?

Comment: new to jackson, but okay i will read custom deserializers. thanks